# Where to find the official specification of Boeing 737-300 fuel consumption rate and such?

Tags: fuel, boeing

I've been doing some work regarding the analysis of boeing 737-300 fuel consumption in commercial flights, and how all of them fare with the fuel consumption standards, like fuel consumption rate at certain flight phases, and such, to like assess how efficient certain flights or routes are in their fuel consumptions

Been finding sources all over internet, but can't sure which one is kinda official and reliable.

So where exactly to look online? are there any documents that would contain such information that is reliable. or better, official?

Comment: The OpenAP open source software package developed at TU Delft has data on the 737-400: https://github.com/junzis/openap/blob/master/openap/data/aircraft/b734.yml
Using this Python package, you can calculate fuel consumption (among other parameters).